# How to pass Variable to Request API in Mozilla Add-on SDK extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm trying to pass the variable value to the [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) of a Mozilla Add-on SDK extension.

In the code below, the `fetch` `Request` is working.  However, when I try requesting another `Request` (`assign`) in the `onCompletion` handler for `fetch`, it says:

```
RequirementError: The option "url" is invalid.
```

How can use the URL I have in the `onCompletion` handler for the `fetch` `Request` for the URL in the `assign` `Request`?

```
var fetch = Request({
    url: 'http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA={%22operation%22:{%22details%22:{%22status%22:%22open%22,%22from%22:0,%22limit%22:500,%22filterby%22:%22Unassigned_System%22}}}&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&format=json',
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
        workorder_id=JSON.parse(response.text).operation.details;
        if(workorder_id!=null){
            assignurl=urls.URL('http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request/'+workorder_id[0].WORKORDERID+'?OPERATION_NAME=EDIT_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&INPUT_DATA= <Details><parameter><name>technician</name><value>'+technician_id[0].NAME+'</value></parameter></Details>');
            console.log(assignurl);
            assign.get();}
        else{fetch.get();}
    }
});

var assign = Request({
    url: assignurl,
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
          var o=technician_id[0];
          for (var k = 0; k < technician_id.length; k++) {
              if (technician_id.length - 1 == k) {
                  technician_id[k] = o;
              } else {
                  technician_id[k] = technician_id[k + 1];
              };
          };
          fetch.get();
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: As written, `assignurl=urls.URL(...` executes well after `url: assignurl,`. Thus, when you `assign.get();` the url is whatever it was prior to the execution of the code shown (i.e. invalid).

Comment: @Makyen may be I'm asking a silly question, however i don't get it how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by the order of execution of your asynchronous code.

As it is written,

```
var assign = Request({
    url: assignurl,
```

executes well before your callback function executes the line providing your `assignurl`:

```
assignurl=urls.URL('http:// ...
```

By calling the [Request() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request#Request(options)), (`var assign = Request({`), you have assigned the `url` as `assignurl` existed at that time. Changing the variable `assignurl` after that point has no affect on the `assign` `Request`.  Thus, you either need to change the `assign.url`, or create the request after you have the URL available.

**NOTE:** The `url` parameter must be present and valid when you call the `Request` constructor.  Thus, I am assuming that your question is incorrect in stating that the error:

```
RequirementError: The option "url" is invalid.
```

only happens from within `onCompletion` handler for `fetch`. It should have happened when you executed the `var assign = Request({url:asignurl` with an invalid `assignurl`.

There are multiple ways you can change your code to use the URL which you now have (from with the `fetch` `onComplete` callback) in the [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) which you are creating for `assign`. Which method you use will depend on if you are going to use the a very similar request to that you use for `assign` in more than one place within your code.

One possible change would be to move the creation of the `assign` `Request` into the `onCompletion` handler for `fetch`:

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var assignurl;          //Unknown from Question
var technician_id=[];   //Unknown from Question
var workorder_id;       //Unknown from Question

var assign;
var fetch = Request({
    url: 'http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA={%22operation%22:{%22details%22:{%22status%22:%22open%22,%22from%22:0,%22limit%22:500,%22filterby%22:%22Unassigned_System%22}}}&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&format=json',
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
        workorder_id=JSON.parse(response.text).operation.details;
        if(workorder_id!=null){
            assignurl=urls.URL('http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request/'+workorder_id[0].WORKORDERID+'?OPERATION_NAME=EDIT_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&INPUT_DATA= <Details><parameter><name>technician</name><value>'+technician_id[0].NAME+'</value></parameter></Details>');
            assign = Request({
                url: assignurl,
                overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
                onComplete: function (response) {
                    var o=technician_id[0];
                    for (var k = 0; k < technician_id.length; k++) {
                        if (technician_id.length - 1 == k) {
                            technician_id[k] = o;
                        } else {
                            technician_id[k] = technician_id[k + 1];
                        };
                    };
                    fetch.get(); //This will throw an error (see below).  Even if it
                                 //  worked it is recursive, which is probably not
                                 //  what you desire.
                }
            });
            console.log(assign.url);
            assign.get();}
        else{
            fetch.get(); //This should always throw an error as you are attempting to
                         //  re-use the Request. In other words, the only way to get
                         //  here is if you have already done fetch.get() once
                         //  and reusing the Request throws an error. 
        }
    }
});
```

If you might issue multiple `assign` requests, you could structure your code such that creating the `assign` `Request` is encapsulated within a `function` which you could call multiple times to create multiple very similar requests, should you have need of doing so elsewhere in your code:

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var technician_id=[];   //Unknown from Question
var workorder_id;       //Unknown from Question

var assign;
var fetch = Request({
    url: 'http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA={%22operation%22:{%22details%22:{%22status%22:%22open%22,%22from%22:0,%22limit%22:500,%22filterby%22:%22Unassigned_System%22}}}&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&format=json',
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
        workorder_id=JSON.parse(response.text).operation.details;
        if(workorder_id!=null){
            assign = setupAssignRequest(urls.URL('http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request/'+workorder_id[0].WORKORDERID+'?OPERATION_NAME=EDIT_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=07109ADB-E642-4F46-917C-CA60F89CE6DC&INPUT_DATA= <Details><parameter><name>technician</name><value>'+technician_id[0].NAME+'</value></parameter></Details>'));
            console.log(assign.url);
            assign.get();}
        else{
            fetch.get(); //As stated above, this should always throw an error.
        }
    }
});

function setupAssignRequest(assignurl) {
    return Request({
        url: assignurl,
        overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
        onComplete: function (response) {
            var o=technician_id[0];
            for (var k = 0; k < technician_id.length; k++) {
                if (technician_id.length - 1 == k) {
                    technician_id[k] = o;
                } else {
                    technician_id[k] = technician_id[k + 1];
                };
            };
            fetch.get(); //If the only code you have is what is shown, this will
                         // throw an error. It is possible that "fetch" has been 
                         // re-initialized with a new call to Request elsewhere
                         // in your code.
        }
    });
}
```

Regarding the `fetch.get();` within your `fetch`'s `onComplete` handler: Trying to do this should always result in throwing an error.  The only way to get to that code is to have already called `fetch.get();` and [each `Request` can only be used once](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request#Request):

> Each Request object is designed to be used once. Attempts to reuse them will throw an error.

Comment: Thanx @Makyen I solved the issue and yes that `fetch.get()` called when  addon initialized

Comment: @user2881430, I have updated the code to something that might actually work (previously, the first code block would produce the same error). I had erroneously relied on my reading of your Question to indicate that the error only occurs within `fetch`'s `onCompletion` handler when it is actually occurring when `var assign = Request({` is executed with an invalid `assignurl`. The probable confusion is that you got `fetch` working then added `assign` at which point the error started showing up (or that is my guess as to the order of things accounting for when the error actually is thrown).